# Power in javascript eval function

Tags: java, javascript

I am using Javascript engine in java to calculate the value of the math expression that I insert as a String. Here is the code:

```
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String infix = "(2^2+5*2+3)%13";
    Double F = (Double) engine.eval(infix);
    int f = F.intValue();
    System.out.println(f);`
```

However, it gives me 0, and the correct solution would be 4. I understand this is because of the ^, because when I tried to write the expression like this "(2*2+5*2+3)%13", I got the correct result. So, my question is how to get power of a number using javascript eval?

Comment: Take a look at [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)

Comment: `^` is the XOR operator.

Comment: Now, I have the follow up question. If I want to use some var x in expression that I input from keyboard, and I want to include that value in exp, how do I do this? I tried like this: String infix = "(Math.pow(x,2)+5*x+3)%13";
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int x = sc.nextInt(); and it gives me an error: "ReferenceError: "x" is not defined"

Comment: Nvm, I got it. Just edited the String like this: String infix = "(Math.pow(" + x + ",2)+5*" + x + "+3)%13";

Comment: A [java] and [javascript] question that actually is relevant to both tags, :D

Answer (score 2):

When using `powr` you need to use the `**` operator instead of `^`:

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String infix = "(2**2+5*2+3)%13";
Double F = (Double) engine.eval(infix);
int f = F.intValue();
System.out.println(f);
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this code and got this exception:
javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:3 Expected an operand but found *
(2**2+5*2+3)%13
   ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 3
(the caret points to the second '*' in the '**' operator.